# D3js how to append 2 children at the same level in .enter context

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having an issue trying to put a circle and a text inside a group (same level, not inside each other) in the .enter() context

```
var categorized = g1.selectAll("g.node").data(dataset, function(d){return d.id})

categorized
.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("id", function(d,i){return d.id;});

categorized
.enter().append("circle")
    .style("fill", "#ddd");
// throws an error

categorized
.append('text')
    .text(function(d,i){return d.count});
// this is working but is an update so I have to remove the text on exit
```

Is there a way to get back to the parent, sg like this:

```
categorized
.enter()
.append("g")
.append("circle")
.getBackToParent // the g
.append("text");
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Just assign the parent d3 wrapper to a variable:

```
var g = categorized.enter().append("g");
g.append("circle").style("fill", "#ddd");
g.append("text").text(function(d,i){return d.count});
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I had a data-binding problem earlier and though using a var with the enter context was part of the problem but it's not.

Comment: This is very useful in `svg`. But what about in `html`, for example to alternate `<dt>` and `<dd>` tags?

Comment: @leonardvertighel: Not sure what you mean, you might want to ask a new question.

Comment: Thanks, I asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116328/how-do-i-create-a-definition-list-with-d3-js : basically I would like to create a list of alternate nodes `<dt>key</dt><dd>value</dd><dt>key</dt><dd>value</dd>...` without a wrapper element

Comment: That is amazing but I was hoping it would be possible some other way.