# How do I create a definition list with d3.js?

Tags: html, d3.js, key-value

I am trying to create a definition list such as this one:

```
<dl>
   <dt>term1</dt>
   <dd>definition1</dd>
   <dt>term2</dt>
   <dd>definition2</dd>
   <dt>term3</dt>
   <dd>definition3</dd>
</dl>
```

by using a JSON in this form:

```
{
  "term1":"definition1"
  "term1":"definition2"
  "term3":"definition3"
}
```

.
Whch is the most elegant way to do it with [d3.js](http://d3js.org)?

**PS:** I would like to use the `<dl>` element because it seems the most appropriate way to semantically represent a key:value pair:

- http://html5doctor.com/the-dl-element/
- [Semantics and Structure of Name-Value Pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281070/semantics-and-structure-of-name-value-pairs)

Comment: What did you end up doing with this?  I just ran across this problem, and I found a solution that doesn't involve wrapping the dt/dd elements in a div (and posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29548501/1281433)), but I'd be interested to know whether you found another solution, too.

Answer (score 8):

#### Solution for d3 v3.x; no longer works as of d3 4.0

I struggled with the same issue for a while.  What I found was the behavior of **insert()**  with the **enter()** selection does the trick.  This is based on the interaction between the enter selection whose inserted or appended elements are merged into the update selection, the the way that insert works with enter selections.  The relevant bits in the documentation:

> #### [selection.enter()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#enter)
>
> … The enter selection merges into the update selection when you
> append or insert.

> #### [selection.insert()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#insert)
>
> … For enter selections, the before selector may be omitted, in which
> case *entering elements will be inserted immediately before the next
> following sibling in the update selection*, if any. This allows you to
> insert elements into the DOM in an order consistent with bound data.

The result is that if you insert some **dt** elements into the enter selection, they will be merged into the update selection.  Then, if you then insert some **dd** elements into the enter selection, they will be "inserted immediately *before* the next following sibling in the update selection";  that is, they'll be right *after* their associated **dt**.

```js
var data = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };
var dl = d3.select("body").append("dl").selectAll().data(Object.keys(data));
dl.enter().insert("dt").text(function(key) { return key });
dl.enter().insert("dd").text(function(key) { return data[key] });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This no longer works; `selection.insert` now (since d3 4.0) defaults to null if you don't give a `before`, rather than inserting before.

Answer (score 3):

When the content is simple like you describe, the easiest way
may be to just directly create paired HTML elements and
bind the data to them afterward.

Also everything is much easier as a list -- D3's [entries function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries) can
easily blow your object out to a list of objects:

```
var pairs = {
  "term1":"definition1",
  "term2":"definition2",
  "term3":"definition3"
};
var pairlist = d3.entries(pairs);  // [{"key":"term1", "value":"definition1"}, etc... ]

var dl = d3.select("dl").html( new Array(pairlist.length + 1).join("<dt/><dd/>") );

dl.selectAll("dt").data(pairlist).html(function(d) { return d.key; });
dl.selectAll("dd").data(pairlist).html(function(d) { return d.value; });
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/slushy/bbh6a4w0/

Comment: You can actually add consecutive elements using the enter selection and the insert method.  I just discovered this a few days ago (and added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29548501/1281433)).  It's sort of a weird case, but I think it ends up being a little bit cleaner.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor hah! That's pretty hot. I'll upvote your answer.

Comment: Though this feels a bit clumsier (no `enter` or `exit`, just scrapping and rebuilding if the data changes), it works on d3 4.0, where @JoshuaTaylor 's doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I would do:

```
list = {
  "term1":"definition1",
  "term2":"definition2",
  "term3":"definition3"
}

dl = d3.select('body').append('dl')
for(var key in list) {
    dl.append('dt').text(key)
    dl.append('dd').text(list[key])
}
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisJamesC/RZdQw/

Then, if you want to be more d3 specific, you can use [selections](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections) ([more about implementation](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/)).

By the way, using arrays might be easier than json objects to represent lists

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment, it works very well. However, this method do not provide data binding, and then no possibility to use the `.enter()`, update, and `.exit()` methods.

Comment: @Christophe you can actually add the consecutive elements using the enter selection.  E.g., you can `var x = d3.select('body').append('dl').selectAll().data(...);  x.enter().insert('dt'); x.enter().insert('dd');`.  I just discovered this when faced with the same problem OP faced.