# How to get out of nested selectAll in D3JS?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Getting reacquainted with hos D3JS works and, in particular `.selectAll/.data/.enter`; learning how to nest data.

I have this working demo:

```js
svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',  640)
  .attr('height', 480);
svg.selectAll('text')
  .data( [ 'hello', 'world' ] )
  .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', function( d, i ) {
      return 20 + i * 20;
    })
    .selectAll('tspan')
    .data( function( d, i ) { // d is from the first data
      return Array.from(d); // if needed, could return an array or object that includes the initial value, too.
    })
    .enter()
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('class', function( d, i ) {
        console.log( 'tspan class:', d, i );
        if ( ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'].includes(d) ) {
          return 'vowel';
        }
      })
      .text( function( d, i, foo ) { // d is from the second data
        console.log( 'tspan text:', d, i, /*foo*/ );
        return d;
      })
    .exit()
    .attr('class', 'strong') // this will set strong on <tspan>, but I wanted it on <text>
    ;
```

(See it on on Codepen: **[*D3JS selectAll SVG nested*](https://codepen.io/fabswt/pen/wvaGKWQ?editors=0111)**.)

Notice how we have two `data()`, with the second (for `<tspan>`s) nested inside the first one (for `<text>`s).

What I'm trying to do:

- I want to **set the `strong` class attribute on `<text>`**.
- I thought `exit()` would get me out of the "scope"/nest of working with the tspans… but I'm wrong.
- If I comment out `exit()`, then the strong class attribute is set on the `<tspan>`s… while I want it on the parent `<text>`!

How can I achieve that, besides:

- Moving the line up (before the second `data()`).
- Using a separate statement (`svg.selectAll('text').attr('class', 'strong');`)

I could use one of these two options and in this example it would be trivial…
But **I want to know if it's possible to get out of nested selections and, if so, how?**

*I hope this was clear enough; if not please comment and I'll clarify :)*

Comment: I tried a lot of things but it doesn't seem possible without using workarounds, hacks, anti-patterns or the two solutions you mentioned.

Comment: For better or for worse, I realized I'd asked in substance the same question two years ago: [D3JS: appending simple nested HTML in a single command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50492373/1717535). The short answer being: "No, you can't get out of nesting." However, you can use variables to break down the code and keep it readable; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50492373/1717535), in particular the last code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

You could think about modifying your original data and that way you could just use one data binding and one update pattern. Within that pattern, you could check/use the word but also check each letter of the word (you could also just do this on the fly later):

```
const test_data = [ 'hello', 'world', 'wthtvwls' ];

const modified_data = test_data.map((item,index) => {
  return {
    word: item,
    array: Array.from(item)
  }
});

console.log(modified_data);
```

Then using this data (demo - https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/qBdZrLv):

```
svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',  640)
  .attr('height', 480);
svg.selectAll('text')
  .data( modified_data )
  .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', function( d, i ) {
      return 20 + i * 20;
    })
    .html(function(d) {      
      return d.letters.map((letter,index) => {
        if (['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'].includes(letter)){
          return '<tspan class="vowel">' + letter + '</tspan>';
        } else{
          return '<tspan>' + letter + '</tspan>';
        }        
      }).join("");
    })   
    .attr('class', function( d, i ) {
        for (letter of d.letters){
          console.log('letter', letter);
          if (['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'].includes(letter)) {
            return 'strong';
          }
        }
      })
    .exit();
```

Note the use of the `.html()` function and then `.map()` within that using our current data.letters in the normal update pattern to add either `'<tspan class="vowel">'` or `'<tspan>'` (no class vowel).

https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/qBdZrLv

But I am not sure if you want such a specific use case or a more general answer to the nested update pattern? If so then maybe this block helps? - https://bl.ocks.org/mpbastos/bd1d6763d34ac5d3ce533a581b291364

**UPDATE - I realize I misread the question the first time**

So it is now clear to me that my one-time solution is no more helpful than the other two solutions suggested by @Fabien (OP) (Moving the line up (before the second data()) or Using a separate statement `svg.selectAll('text').attr('class', 'strong');`)

I tried patterns such as:

```
svg.selectAll('text')
    .data( test_data )
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', 10)
    ...
    .selectAll('tspan')
    .data( ...)
    .enter()
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('class', 'example')
    .exit()
    .select(this.ParentNode)
    .attr('class', 'example')
```

And also with the `.select(this.ParentNode)` before the `.exit()` but neither worked.

The only thing that works but it is also a workaround and probably an anti-pattern is this - hijack the attr function to "grab" parent outside nested update :

```
svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr('width',  640)
  .attr('height', 480);
text = svg.selectAll('text')
    .data( test_data )
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .attr('x', 10)
    .attr('y', function( d, i ) {
      return 20 + i * 20;
    })
    .selectAll('tspan')
    .data( function( d, i ) { // d is from the first data
      return Array.from(d); // if needed, could return an array or object that includes the initial value, too.
    })
    .enter()
      .append('tspan')
      .attr('class', function( d, i ) {
        console.log(1, i, this.parentNode);
         //hijack the attr function to "grab" parent outside nested update pattern
        if (i == 0) {
          d3.select(this.parentNode).attr('class', 'strong');
        }
        //console.log( 'tspan class:', d, i );
        if ( ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'].includes(d) ) {
          return 'vowel';
        }
      })
      .text( function( d, i, foo ) { // d is from the second data
        //console.log( 'tspan text:', d, i, /*foo*/ );
        return d;
      })    
    .exit();
```

This is also not a beautiful solution.

I think because once the `.data()` function is called on a selection, it is now longer a normal node list object, and the `.exit()` function is only designed to be used one layer deep.

I think the two solutions the OP outlined are the best, but I would love to be proven wrong!

Comment: I should have mentioned I wanted to avoid using .html() too, because it feels like the library should be handling the creation of elements. Not sure there a pattern for  my original question… played with more nesting… and ended up just setting a variable for the top parent and working with that; felt the most readable.